# Passing data from child to parent to parent in Vue.js with method $emit()

Tags: vue.js, parent-child

I can't pass data from child to parent routers with vue.js.

From few research, including on stack overflow, it is very clear that we must use the $emit() method from the child.
I played around between the documentation, stackoverflow and some youtube tutorials but there is still something I miss and I do wrong.

Below is my router Menubar.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
         <div @clicked="onClickChild">
            <p>login is set to {{ loggedin }}</p>
            <p>Route query login {{ this.$route.query.loggedin }}</p>
        </div>
        <div v-if="!loggedin">
            <nav>
                <!--<router-link class="btn btn-primary" to="/">Customers</router-link>-->
                <router-link class="btn btn-primary" to= "/menubar/login">Login</router-link>
                <router-link class="btn btn-primary" to="/menubar/register">Register</router-link>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <nav>
                <!--<router-link class="btn btn-primary" to="/">Customers</router-link>-->
                <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="logout()">Logout</button>
                <router-link class="btn btn-primary" to="/edit">Edit</router-link>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <br/>
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "menubar",
        data(){
            return{
                loggedin:false,
            }
        },
        created() {
            if(this.$route.query.loggedin){
                this.loggedin = this.$route.query.loggedin;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            logout(){
                this.loggedin = false;
            },
            onClickChild (value) {
                this.loggedin = value;
                console.log(value) // someValue
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And its child Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="submitform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required v-model="user.username" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" required v-model="user.password" name="password">
        </div>

        <button v-on:click="logUser()" class="btn btn-success">Connect</button>
</template>

<script>
    import router from '../../router'

    export default {
        name: "login",
        data(){
            return{
                user: {
                    id: 0,
                    username: "",
                    password: ""
                },
            }
        },
        methods:{
            logUser(){
                var loggedin = true;
                this.$emit('clicked', loggedin);
                router.push({ name: "menubar" });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

my router.js

```
{
        path: "/menubar",
        name: "menubar",
        component: Menubar,
        children: [
            {
                path: "login",
                name: "login",
                component: Login,
            },
            {
                path: "register",
                name: "register",
                component: Register,
            }
        ]
    }
```

the console.log should print true or false to give track my params 'loggedin'
Instead, no idea if this is linked, I have this:
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

which gives in my mozilla browser (same in Chrome):

> The address wasn’t understood
>   Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following > protocols (view-source, webpack) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.
>   You might need to install other software to open this address."

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the component listening to the event is not a component child:

```
<div @clicked="onClickChild">[...]</div>
```

Here the child is a div, however, if you want to be able to listen to an emit
signal from a child component, the listener should be associated with this specific child component. In this case something like:

```
<Login @clicked="onClickChild">[...]</Login>
```

However, if you want to pass data from a child to a parent node in the router
you can define a router-view and catch the event like so:

```
<router-view @clicked="onClickChild" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like your child component is emitting the event correctly to the parent. For the error you are receiving in the browser, it's likely to be a typo or a bad URL, as you are doing:

```
        path: "/menubar",
        name: "menubar",
        component: Menubar,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/menubar/login",
```

Which will produce a path like /menubar/menubar/login which looks wrong.  https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: Good point, I have changed the children to path: "login". It is cleaner however it doesn't change the behavior: I can still navigate back and forth from child to parent and no parameters are passed